# Control Web Page

Tags: android, web

I'm writing my first Android app. Well, actually my second. I followed a tutorial to create a "Hello World" app in Eclipse. My second app will be for work. I want to direct users to page on our site where they will log in and then I will direct them to a second page for them to view a schedule.

What I don't want is to put a short cut to a page that will be opened in the default browser, which they can do other things with. I want to keep it simple for both myself - as a new Android developer - and for them.

Can anyone direct me to a web page control or maybe a sample app that would allow me to program a web page window in my app. I want to be able to hide address bars so it looks as if it is prat of the application and not a web page. I would also like to save their credentials so they only have to log in the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [WebViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).
These are windows that show a webpage without all the extra stuff like adress bars.
Here are some quick tutorials on how to use them:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html
- http://www.androidpeople.com/android-webview-example-part-1
- http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html

That should get you started. Just let us know if you need any more help.

As for saving the credentials and logging in automatically, I'm afraid that won't work. If you direct your users to your log in page, unless you build in some method in your webpage that allows you to call a certain link containing their credentials, you won't be able to log in automatically.

By using a certain link containing their credentials I mean something like this:

```
yoursite.com/somefolder/login.php?username=theirusername&password=theirpassword
```

That page could check the crendentials and then automatically open the schedule page. That would work as logging in automatically but it's not such a secure way to handle this.

Then again, I'm no expert when it comes logging people in remotely so there might be other ways of doing this, this just seems like the easiest method from the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Good point about the security. Since I will be controlling both ends I could hash the username and password. There won't be anything too mission critical and sensitive with this schedule checker.